# changing the value in ASCII file and saving it as with different name - Python

Tags: python, ascii

I have one ASCII file with .dat extention. The file has a data as shown below,

```
MPOL3_VPROFILE
{
  ID="mpvp_1"  Cycle="(720)[deg]"  Lift="(9)[mm]"  Period="(240)[deg]"
  Phase="(0)[deg]"  TimingHeight="(1.0)[mm]"  RampTypeO="Const Velo"
  RampHO="(0.3)[mm]"  RampVO="(0.00625)[mm/deg]"  RampTypeC="auto"
  RampHC="(auto)[mm]"  RampVC="(auto)[mm/deg]"  bO="0.7"  cO="0.6"  dO="1.0"
  eO="1.5"  bC="auto"  cC="auto"  dC="auto"  eC="auto"  th1O="(14)[deg]"
```

Now I would like to read this file in Python and then change the value of RampHO="(0.3)[mm]" to lets say RampHO="(0.2)[mm]" and save it as a new .dat file. How can I do this ?

Currently I am able to read the file and line successfully using below code,

```
import sys
import re
import shutil
import os
import glob
import argparse
import copy
import fileinput

rampOpen = 'RampHO='
file = open('flatFollower_GenCam.dat','r')

#data = file.readlines()

#print (data)


for line in file:
    line.strip().split('/n')
    if rampOpen in line:
        print (line[4:22])
```

But I am now stuck how to change the float value and save it as with different name.

Comment: Why don't you post your text as text but post it as a picture?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Why on Earth you want to insert a picture of TEXT? Post the text!

Comment: Added a text now instead of image...

Comment: If you are not bound to python, this looks like a job for sed.

Answer (score 0):

First up, you should post your code inside your text and not in seperate images. Just indent each line with four spaces to format it as code.

You can simply read in a file line by line, change the lines you want to change and then write the output.

```
with open(infile, 'r') as f_in, open(outfile, 'w') as f_out:
    for line in f_in:
        output_line = edit_line(line)
        f_out.write(output_line)
```

Then you just have to write a function that does the string replacement.

Comment: Thanks ! I gave indentation and it converted to code.